# Create setup for Winforms application and SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, installation, setup-project, localdb

I have a C# Winforms application using a SQL Server database. I want to create a setup with that database. I'd like to install only `SqlLocalDb.msi` on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to at least install MS Sql Server Express, and choose the features you want during installation. You can select Local DB from the list of features. (I'm assuming you have just tried to install a minimal .msi to remedy your situation)
Try this link for Express Edition: [sql-server-downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)